# Stack Exchange experimentation sandbox

Tags: support

This is a sandbox post for users to experiment with various Stack Exchange features. This question (and all answers) is a community wiki so that the reputation required to edit is lower.

Also, the user who owns this post is set to [Community](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), which is not a real user but a background process. So you needn't worry that some one might be notified by all your shenanigans here (do note that comments on others' answers will still notify them).

Feel free to post an answer (gibberish welcome), delete your answers as you wish, try out various formatting tricks, test out voting to close/delete, protect posts, test new privileges, whatever the hell you want ([yes, really!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)). Of course, as always, offensive content/spam will not be tolerated.

I merely request that you do not change the title of this post or add any new arbitrary tags. If you do cast the last close/delete vote or if it is not reopened, please let a ♦ moderator know so that we can reopen/undelete it.

Feel free to modify the question below this line

Test edit to test rollbacks stuff

---

Comment: Yikes, stern message! No promoting going on ... only that in the windowsphone stackexchange this tag [windowsphone.com] wasn't allowed through so I needed/wanted to find out if this was global to stackexchange or unique to windowsphone.stackexchange (the latter if you're interested). I figured I could test it on a genuine post in the main gardening site - and roll it straight back, or else I could try the _sandbox_ in meta.gardening and if I forgot to roll it back (as indeed I did) it wouldn't matter... as if I'd vandalize this site!!!

Comment: @TeaDrinker Oops :) Well, I didn't think you'd do it intentionally, but I was concerned because there was no  context to it (e.g., you could've left a note in the edit message) and there wasn't a rollback either. Since the question requests not to add random tags, I was concerned if you went bersek or your account got hacked! :) Sorry about the confusion. My apologies — Ι probably should've been discreet in talking to you about it. I've removed the comments so I don't libel you anymore :)

Comment: @TeaDrinker To answer your question on why "windowsphone" couldn't be added on that site — Tags which are redundant on a site cannot be added. For example, you cannot add "gardening" to any question on our main site. In addition to these, they also block any site that is frequently spammed (either here or elsewhere on the network). To see our blacklisted input, look here: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/admin/blacklist

Comment: ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍

Comment: ‍‍‍‍‍Wrong.‍‍‍‍

Comment: Oh, fun, no limit. :)

Answer (score 3):

[image: sedum in new home]
[image: closeup of plant]

Comment: How to do this [help/dont-ask]

Comment: Testing shortcut for how to ask [ask] and how to answer [answer]

Comment: Testing shortcut for link to help center [help] and link to tour [tour]

Comment: Testing comment shortcut for what can I ask [help/on-topic] and what not to ask [help/dont-ask] and what type of behavior [help/behavior]

Comment: Testing shortcut to main site [main] and edit [edit] and chat [chat]

Comment: Testing to shortcut to what is meta [meta-help]

Comment: Testing to see if I can make the edit shortcut say editing. I need to [edit] my question because [edit] (hoping it will say editing) will improve it. Unfortunately it didn't work!

Comment: Testing to see if help/closed-questions in brackets leads to the page explaining why questions might be closed [help/closed-questions] Nope! Guess that's why I couldn't find it on the comment shortcuts page!

Answer (score 3):

Gibberish is welcome Gibberish is welcome Gibberish is welcome

Comment: Thank you!  - <mr. gibberish>

Answer (score 2):

[image: size of plant]

[image]

I'm testing to see if shortcut links will work in the edit summary. I'll try the shortcut to the help center, [help]. Answer: No :)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> **Thanks for your edit!**
>   This edit will be visible only to you until it
>   is peer reviewed. Just kidding, your edit was horrible, and nobody cared enough to accept it.

Testing different ways to embed links to learn the fewest number of characters necessary.

Example:
https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8570/back-country-solution-to-itchy-insect-bites

Link to [entire question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8570/back-country-solution-to-itchy-insect-bites)

Link to [number with / on the end](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8570/)

Link to [site/number/ without the word questions](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/8570/) This one didn't work. All others did.

Link to [question without the / on end](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8570)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is test number 2 test number 2.

Answer (score 1):

[image]